# byrow= TRUE argument in matrix function for R

Tags: r, matrix

I read in somewhere that when creating a matrix, R stores the elements of the matrix in a vector as a column major format with additional information about the matrix dimensions.

If

```
matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
```

R internally stores values as a vector of `1:6`.

However, if we set `byrow = TRUE`, does it mean R is storing values as `c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)`?

Comment: Why don't you try for yourself? E.g. compare `as.numeric(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = T))` with `as.numeric(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2))` or compare `str(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2, byrow = T))` with `str(matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, ncol = 2))`...

Comment: Are you asking about how the matrix is stored at the RAM level when you talk about "column major format"? I don't think that changes based on `byrow = TRUE`, I think all the C code that powers R's vector/matrix operations would be based around column major order.

Comment: Yes, I am referring to the RAM level. What I am asking is if `x = matrix(1:6, 3, 2, byrow = TRUE)` then whether `x` is internally stored as `1:6` or `c(1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6)`?

Comment: From the OO side: Encapsulation says that what goes on inside the structure is irrelevant (and may change). 
You can look under the covers, but what you see should not change how you use the function.

Answer (score 4):

The `byrow = TRUE` tells R that it needs to manipulate the input to get it to the column-major order. So yes, `matrix(1:6, nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)` stores the values as `1 3 5 2 4 6` internally - it reorders them before creating the matrix.

We can verify this in a couple ways. First, we can compare two matrices with the same values, one created with `byrow = TRUE` and one not, and see that they are the same:

```
by_col = matrix(1L:4L, 2)
by_row = matrix(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), 2, byrow = TRUE)
identical(by_col, by_row)
# [1] TRUE
```

We can also examine the structure of the "by-row" matrix and see that nothing in the data structure keeps track of the fact that it was created with `byrow = TRUE`:

```
# notice the order is 1 2 3 4, not the input order 1 3 2 4
str(by_row)
# int [1:2, 1:2] 1 2 3 4
dput(by_row)
# structure(1:4, .Dim = c(2L, 2L))
```

With a big enough matrix for the difference to matter, we can observe the extra processing time needed to create a matrix by row:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  by_col = matrix(1:1e6, nrow = 1000),
  by_row = matrix(1:1e6, nrow = 1000, byrow = TRUE),
  times = 100
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
#  by_col  2.071366  2.214147  5.943154  4.474175  5.512274 92.49424   100
#  by_row 10.513797 11.112386 15.700628 13.850260 14.485675 98.94681   100
```

On a 1000x1000 matrix, it takes about 3x longer to create a matrix `byrow`, because R needs to manipulate the data into column-major format.

Finally, if you want to be really ambitious, you can look through the C source code for creating matrices, and see how the `byrow` argument is used internally. [Here are the relevant lines](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/21ffd5856402ad77978036071747adcaa5ed5897/src/main/duplicate.c#L413). My C isn't great, but it looks to me like the `byrow = TRUE` just does a bit of extra processing, reordering the input to column-major order, before doing the same thing as `byrow = FALSE`.

Comment: @ Gregor: "The `byrow = TRUE` only tells R that it needs to manipulate the input to get it to the column-major order." Doesn't it mean that the manipulated vector is now stored in that order (i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4; in your case) than the original order (i.e., 1, 3, 2, 4)

Comment: Yes - I re-read your question and edited my response to make it more of a direct answer.