# Form a matrix from a vector in r

Tags: r

Suppose I have vector:

```
v <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2)
```

I would like to form a matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

I use `matrix(v, 2,5)`, but provide

```
matrix(v, 2,5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    2    2
[2,]    1    1    2    2    2
```

Comment: Use `byrow = TRUE, ncol = 5`. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51255759/byrow-true-argument-in-matrix-function-for-r) provides some good information, I think.

Answer (score 0):

```
> matrix( v, nrow=2, ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2    2
```

Use **byrow = TRUE**; by default it is **FALSE**. You can check the details of matrix function using **help(matrix)**.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many ways to transfer the vector to the matrix of desired, and here are two of possible approaches to make it

```
do.call(rbind,split(v,seq(v)%/%(length(v)/2+1)))
```

or

```
matrix(v,nrow = 2,byrow = TRUE)
```